# Python отправка команд кард-ридеру ICT3K5

Tags: python

Добрый день.Пытаюсь разобраться в принципах взаимодействия с устройством.
Вместе с доками поставляется тулза для отправки команд.
1й скрин - команда инициализации, 2й - принятие карты.
Ввожу все, как в в поле command, но устройство не реагирует.
Сижу в банкомате под teamveawer поэтому извиняюсь за плохое качество
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 38400, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN)

ser.write(b'\x43\x30\x30\x33\x32\x34\x31\x30\x30\x31\x30\x30\x30')
time.sleep(0.5)
ser.write(b'\x43\x3A\x30')
ser.close()
```

Comment: Настройки порта какие? У вас serial.Serial('COM3', 38400) на скринах их нет. Что с битами данных, стоп-битами и четностью?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов [на 10 странице](https://vk.com/doc65889999_437876472) описан формат данных

Comment: Еще раз: настройки порта. А именно: скорость, число бит данных, четность, число стоповых битов. Не формат данных, а параметры передачи. И нужны они не мне, а вам для корректной настройки вашей софтины.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов программа работает корекктно.Она поставляется вместе с документацией и она изображена на скрине.Из всех настроек там только скорость, которая выставлена в 38400.В принципе утройство поддерживает до 115200

Comment: вы можете считать что настройки порта это только скорость, но минимальные настройки я указал выше. Пока вы не выставите в Питоне ровно те же настройки, что и в софтине, ни о каком поиске проблем не может быть и речи.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Parity check method: Vertical (Even), Data length :8bit + 1 parity, Stop bit : 1 bit. Исправил код в примере

Comment: Точно even, а не NoParity? Нечастая настройка...
Теперь берете терминалку с поддержкой отображения в HEX, вешаете ее на другой порт, коннектите этот порт с COM3 и шлете команду из софтины и из скрипта. Должно совпадать по длине и байтам.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов И действительно эта программа в начало добавляет пару байтов, которые не отображаются в логах.Сейчас буду разбираться откуда они берутся.Можно было самому додуматься воспользоваться терминалом и сверить данные.Спасибо большое!